# gulp-sass compiles Google Fonts CSS into the file, breaks protocol-relative link

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass, protocol-relative, gulp-clean-css

When I use the following code in my `.scss` file

```
@import url('//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=SomeFont:400,700,400italic');
```

the SASS parser I use (nodejs `gulp-sass`) happily downloads the file from said location and includes it as plain text in the compiled output.

Here's my Gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    minify = require('gulp-minify-css'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('www/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            this.emit('end');
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass({
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                errLogToConsole: true,
            }))
            .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min' }))
            .pipe(minify())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/css'));
});
```

Problem is, my site uses `HTTPS`, and when the file is requested by the compiler, it fetches the file using `HTTP` and as such the URLs in the returned response are also `HTTP` which results in loads of warnings filling up the console, while the fonts would not load.

Is there any way I could tell the compiler to leave that line alone?

Comment: Cannot reproduce, your problem is not with Sass: http://sassmeister.com/gist/7651112d36e67a3cee8d

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The issue was not with `gulp-sass` itself, but with `gulp-minify-css` that did the compression of the rendered CSS files. The solution is to pass `{processImport: false}` to `minify`:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    gulp.src('www/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(plumber(function(err){
            console.log(err);
            this.emit('end');
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(sass({
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                errLogToConsole: true,
            }))
            .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min' }))

            // Here
            .pipe(minify({processImport: false}))

        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('www/css'));
});
```

Comment: I attempted many other alternatives to this solution, because I wanted the font css to be inline in my minified css file. I also had another website that seemed to accept the import without timing out.

However, this was the only solution that worked for my one case. So strange, but nonetheless it was. Would love to know why some google font imports don't timeout and others do.

Answer (score 0):

[Protocol relative URLs are now discouraged](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/). I would suggest setting the URL to HTTPS and leaving it that way.

Comment: Maybe but that doesn't fix the problem in the question.