# Remote font imports with css minification

Tags: css, gulp, google-font-api, gulp-minify-css, gulp-clean-css

I'm trying to concatenate & minify all bower package assets including css. One of them is bootswatch design and it imports google fonts. Problem is, running css tasks on it results in timeout exception. I'm guessing it is trying to download those fonts and it takes too long as exception does not occur every single time.

How would I go about resolving it?

Gulp imports:

```
var gulpMinifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var gulpConcatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');
var gulpFilter = require('gulp-filter');
```

Gulp task:

```
gulp.task('compileBowerCss', function(){
    return gulp
        .src(mainBowerFiles())
        .pipe(gulpFilter('*.css'))
        .pipe(gulpConcatCss('bower.css'))
        .pipe(gulpMinifyCss())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(assetsFolder + cssFolder));
});
```

Exception:

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: Broken @import declaration of "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" - timeout
```

Running this task alone and nothing else works fine always (as far as I can tell with limit testing), but running it in conjuction with other tasks results in mentioned error.

Comment: Same issue when i'm using bootswatch instead of pure bootstrap

Comment: solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32001352/gulp-sass-compiles-google-fonts-css-into-the-file-breaks-protocol-relative-link?rq=1

Comment: FYI gulp-minify-css has been [deprecated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-css) in favor of [gulp-clean-css](https://github.com/scniro/gulp-clean-css)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'd same bug. Solution: pass **processImport: false** option to minifyCss pipe.

```
.pipe(gulpMinifyCss({processImport: false}))
```

Comment: Saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately it removes the power that is prefetching the import so it doesn't have to do it on page load :-\. But thanks for the pointer, def helpful patch

Answer (score 0):

Try localizing your font with npm: https://libraries.io/npm/roboto-font